# jps can't connect to a remote jstatd

Tags: java, monitoring

I'm trying query a remote JVM with jps using jstatd, in order to eventually monitor it using VisualVM.

I got jstatd running with the following security policy:

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {

    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

jstatd is running on a 64-bit Linux box with a 1.6.0_10 version HotSpot vm.  The jstatd command is:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.tools.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true
```

I'm trying to run jps from a Windows 7 machine.  Due to firewall restrictions, I'm tunneling the RMI data through an SSH tunnel to my Windows machine such that the jps command line is:

```
 .\jps.exe -m -l rmi://localhost
```

When I run jps, I see the connection attempt in the jstatd log, which looks like this:

```
Feb 1, 2011 11:50:34 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(ja   va.lang.String)]
```

but on the jps side I get the following error:

```
Error communicating with remote host: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.137; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Based on the connection attempt listed in the jstatd log, I think jps is actually reaching the host, but for some reason is getting blocked.  Is there some security policy I have set or some other setting somewhere I can change so that I can get jps to pull stats from the remote jstatd?

Comment: It could be that I haven't set the jmxremote properties in the application I want to monitor, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726643/get-heap-dump-from-a-remote-application-in-java-using-jvisualvm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that you're only forwarding the RMI registry port (1099), but you need to also open another port.

Check which ports on the remote side

```
# netstat -nap | grep jstatd

tcp        0      0 :::1099     :::*       LISTEN      453/jstatd          
tcp        0      0 :::58204    :::*       LISTEN      453/jstatd
```

In this case you will need to forward port 58204 as well as 1099

Comment: No, that didn't help.  I tunneled to the other port, 45998 in my case, but jps still could not connect.

Comment: The tunneling didn't help, but opening more ports did.  You were right.  Thanks.

Comment: @afrosteve: can you explain which other ports you opened and which one you tunneled?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could easily do this.

1. Launch [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) in your remote host this way (executing from the ejstatd folder): `mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="-pr 2000 -ph 2001 -pv 2002"`
2. Open those 3 ports on your remote host and make them available to your local machine: `2000`, `2001` and `2002`
3. On your local machine, you will be able to use `jps` replacing `<remotehost>` with your remote host name: `jps -m -l rmi://<remotehost>:2000`

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the open source [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) tool