# Firewall rules for jstatd

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm, jstatd

I'm trying to run a jstatd on a remote server. According to the documentation I created a policy file and startet the deamon with the following command:

`jstatd -p 1199 -J-Djava.security.policy=<path-to-policy>`

In the following posts I read that there are 2 ports I must open in my firewall: [jps can't connect to a remote jstatd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865650/jps-cant-connect-to-a-remote-jstatd)

After opening these 2 ports everything works fine (including connection to my remote Java-Applications via VisualVM). Now I've read that 1199 port is fix, but the second one is a random port at each startup of the jstatd ([Using VisualVM to connect to a remote jstatd instance through a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424519/using-visualvm-to-connect-to-a-remote-jstatd-instance-through-a-firewall)). That makes my firewall ruling quite complicated. Is there any possibility to set the port to a fixed value? My problem is that I can't change the firewall every time the jstatd is (re)started.

Thanks in advance for your help and best regards,
AnarchoEnte

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution is to use ssh tunnel with SOCKS proxy created via `ssh -D`. Once you have it, set the SOCKS proxy in VisualVM preferences. See [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm) article at DZone for detailed info.